# IBM Mobile First - Json Store not working on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, x86-64, jsonstore

We're building a hybrid app with IBM Mobile First Platform (7.0) for iOS and Android platforms. We're using JSONStore to save user non-confidential data (we're not cyphering the data stored).

When we deploy the application to a Samsung Galaxy S6 (Model SM-G920I) we're having this error on the init method of the Json Store:

**Error code:** -11 OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT
[IBM Mobile First Platform - JSONStore errors](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_errorcodes.html)

**Error details**: "dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.MyMobileApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit"

Making some research, we cannot figure out something else than the lack of the libraries for x86_64 android devices for IBM Mobile First Platform, as mentioned here: [JSONStore initalization fails with PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE (Dalvik) / OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT (ART)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528327/jsonstore-initalization-fails-with-persistent-store-failure-dalvik-operation)

Does anyone knows any workaround for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention the full build number of your MFPF 7.0 installation, so I can only assume you are missing the following recent fix: PI43196 JSONSTORE DOES NOT CORRECTLY IDENTIFY X86_64 ARCHITECTURE  PROCESSORS ON MOBILE DEVICES

Go to IBM Fix Central and download the latest available Studio artifact for MFPF 7.0 and try again.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. We're now on MFPF 7.0.0.00.20150729-1801. Just as a note, after installing the fix pack, we had to delete the Android environment and re create a new one for the fix to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this issue in xamarin then perform below steps,

1. Project-RightClick -- > Options
2. Under Build choose Android Build
3. Go to Advanced Tab
4. Uncheck arm64-v8a and x86_64
5. Save and run the project again

[32-bit instead of 64 bit error fix in xamarin for ibm worklight json store connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBY0m.png)