# JsonStore error 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have an issue with a MobileFirst Cordova project, build with android studio. When I try to do something with the JsonStore I have an this issue:

```
com.ibm.myApp D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils: WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:553 :: os.arch: aarch64
com.ibm.myApp D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils: WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:574 :: Extracting zip file: featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
com.ibm.myApp E/art: dlopen("/data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
com.ibm.myApp D/WebView: setNetworkAvailable=false
com.ibm.myApp D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils: WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:584 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
com.ibm.myApp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "error happened : {
  src": "initCollection",
  err": -11,
  msg": "OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT",
  col": "pictures",
  usr": "jsonstore",
  doc": "dlopen failed: \"/data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0\" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit",
  res": {}
  }", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/services/JSONstore.service.js (59)
com.ibm.myApp D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils: WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:589 :: com.mobileiron.wrapped is set to false
com.ibm.myApp D/WebView: setNetworkAvailable=true
com.ibm.myApp D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils: WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:594 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
com.ibm.myApp E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin: DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run in DispatchingPlugin.java:83 :: error while dispatching action "provision"
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
      at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
      at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
      at com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils.loadLib(WLUtils.java:595)
      at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.<init>(WLJSONStore.java:72)
      at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.getInstance(WLJSONStore.java:274)
      at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.initializeCollection(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:148)
      at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:138)
      at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
      at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
      at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
com.ibm.myApp E/wl.jsonstore: {"src":"initCollection","err":-11,"msg":"OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT","col":"pictures","usr":"jsonstore","doc":"dlopen failed: \"/data/data/com.ibm.myApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0\" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit","res":{}}
com.ibm.myApp D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:140] onCreateInputConnection returns null.
```

I tried to change libcrypto.so.1.0.0.zip and i have the same issue.

I work with MFP 7.1 and i saw this post but i was for MFP 7.0 [IBM Mobile First - Json Store not working on Samsung Galaxy S6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821453/ibm-mobile-first-json-store-not-working-on-samsung-galaxy-s6)

Comment: What is your exact MFP version?

Comment: 7.1.0.0-MFPF-CLI-IF201602291240

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question what is your 7.1 build number.
Even though the APAR is for 7.0, the fix was merged for all releases and you should download the latest iFix also for 7.1 from IBM Fix Central: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43196

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines of code into build.gradle

```
defaultConfig { // inside of defaulConfig

//Add ndk

 ndk {
     abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
   }
}
```