# JSONStore error due to library being 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

This question [was previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821453/ibm-mobile-first-json-store-not-working-on-samsung-galaxy-s6) but for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and 7.1. However I am experiencing this issue in v8.0. See image below.

We're using:

1. cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016122615
2. cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2016110713

[image: error X86]

Comment: What is the device you are testing with? Model, OS, etc...

Comment: @idanAdar , we're using samsung(S6, Note 5), OS marshmallow..

additional note on mfpdev version, 
we're using 8.0.0-2016121916 version, just recently upgrade(like a week or two weeks ago)

Comment: @idanAdar, additional info, i recently implemented cordova-sqlite-storage for a very big data, is it possible because of this?

but this didn't happen in my LG G5 phone
- XiaoMi mi 5 also error
- all samsung phone got error also

Comment: Well, if you remove it, does it work?

Comment: @idanAdar , will try it now, will comment the result

Comment: @IdanAdar it worked after i remove the plugin and all the related coding to it. i wonder why because i want to use both of the plugin

Comment: It could be that it somehow changes that lib to not support 64bit, because JSONStore in itself does support 64bit (tested). I suggest to contact the other of the other plug-in you're attempting to use.

Comment: @idanAdar okay, thank you idan! will update the answered section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with Idan,

I have come up with conclusion that the cordova-SQLite-storage was causing JSONStore failed to initialize when trying to get libcrypto for 64 bit (tested by myself, see the comment section of the question)

after SQLite storage were delete:

[image: after sqlite storage were delete]

I will try to contact the other plugin provider.

Hope this help